# Echo the 2 last columns of tabel

Tags: php, sql

I have a table and i want to echo the 2 last rows of my tabel, I used the below code but just the last one showed, what is the problem.

```
$result1 =(mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2")));

Print $result1['time'];
```

Comment: 1. Don't use `mysql_` functions. They are deprecated. 2. You will have to continuously call this function in order to move the pointer and get the next row.

Comment: last 2 COLUMNS or last two ROWS???

Comment: @zdhickman why souldn't i use mysql ???

Comment: @STTLCU you are right, last 2 rows

Comment: @alexisLeone [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: but when i use mysqli insted of sql it cuase error, what to do?

Comment: You don't have to simply replace any "mysql_" you see with a "mysqli_", you need to change something here and there...

Comment: so could you tell me how to update my sql code to sqli ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 2 Or more rows you need to loop it

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2")

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo $row['time']."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_fetch_array` = 1 fetch.

do it again for fetching 2nd result.

Also, use mysqli eh.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing `mysql_fetch_array` only one time, so it gets the first element. If you want to get all the elements, then do it again, or use a loop.

Something like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query) )
{
    echo $row['time'].'<br>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
$limit = 2;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$array = array(); $i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $array[$i] = $row;
    $i++;
}

var_dump($array[0]);
var_dump($array[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2");
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $result['time'];
}
```

Gives out every return of your database (2 in this case). You should use mysqli_-functions.

Comment: as it is deprecated and will be removed in the future.

Comment: see this link for further information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli

Comment: but when i use mysqli insted of sql it cuase error, what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try like this, since mysql_fetch_array returns only one row

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($yourQuery)) {
    echo $row["yourAlias"];
}
```

Further details here : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php